# Change <img> src according to it's alt attribute

Tags: javascript

How to change an image **src** according to it's unique **alt** attribute by using a for loop targeted by document.querySelectorAll(img) using vanilla JS. Ty

This

`<img src="../../img/potatoes.png" alt="potatoes">`

Into

`<img src="../../img/potatoes/newpotatoes.png" alt="potatoes">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get specific elements

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).filter(function(img){
    return img.alt === 'potatoes';
}).forEach(function(img){
  img.src = img.src.replace('.png', '/new' + img.alt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + img.alt.slice(1) + '.png')
});
```

Comment: Awesome, will that work to target the specific "potatoes" alt tag or it will change all img tag sources into newPotatoes? If I have multiple images with different alt tags how can I specify only the one with the unique alt tag potatoes? Ty for your time and apologies for so many potatoes.

Comment: I have edited my answer, it will work with any number of images, if any of the img alt tag is 'potatoes' it will be replaced.